# animation doesn't work when I press back on ajax search

Tags: javascript

I have done back function for ajax search using url hash. It works fine but the problems is with sliders and some other animation, the sliders freezing and I can't move crawlers.

```
var hashState = false;
var historyState = false;
var historyArr = new Array();
    // back content with specific hash
window.onhashchange = function(){
    var hash = location.hash;
    if( ! hashState && hash && historyArr[hash])
    {
        $('.diamond-filter').html(historyArr[hash]);
        historyState = true;
        $('#diamond_search').ajaxForm(diamonds_options);
        $('#diamond_search').submit();
    }
    hashState = false;
    return false;
};

function logSearch(hash)
{
    historyArr[hash] = $('.diamond-filter').html();
}
```

I suppose it losing some connection. How to keep it or restore without re-init?